# Is there any filed in contact database from that we know contact is updated in Android?

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is any field in Android contact database that knows contact is updated,deleted or newly added?. Let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure but I think you do not have this in sqlite. This is not feature from android , it is coming from the database, as 'lite' says there are a lot of functionalities that doesn't exist in sqlite in comparison to SQL or mySql databasese.

But look at the brite side you always have the option to create a field in database like 'updatedTime' and manually update this field with some time-stamp every time when you insert or edit that row.

Comment: Well, is there any way like broadcast(Action) contact when they are added, updated or deleted from Phone?...so I can do work on that action..

Comment: I far I know there is no such an action. And when working with sqlite always keep in mind that is 'lite' very lite version of SQL.